# loading multiple files using the options from menu bar in java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jmenu, jmenubar

I have developed an editor using java Jpanel, component, etc....I have 2 text areas in the editor. When i choose open a file option from the menubar i'm able to load the content of the file to one textarea. But how can i add another option to the menu bar to load the content of another file to the second text box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add two menu items, passing a reference to the desired destination text area to each [`Action`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html). Alternatively, depending on your design, add a single menu item whose [`Action`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) alternates between the two destination text areas.